# Getting exceptions from child domain to parent domain

Tags: .net, appdomain

I'm trying to figure out how I can get all unhandled exceptions from a ***child*** appdomain to the parent domain.

Just hooking `childDomain.UnhandledException` doesn't work since it seems to be executed in the childDomain.

And I've played around with `domain.DoCallback` but I can't figure out how do use it to get the exception back.

All ideas are most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgot to make the class that I used in `AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap` to inherit `MarshalByRefObject`. Everything works fine after doing so.